# LocationClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, gps, location

so yeah basically that's my issue, i have been following this link http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

and it seems that eclipse won't identify the LocationClient class and it doesn't even ask me to import it, of course i implemented the GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener and my activity extends FragmentActivity

Am i missing something ??

Also i found out the the overridden onConnected() method has no parameters, i've seen examples from all over and everywhere i see it says onConnected(Bundle bundle) but mine just refuses to have parameters.
Any help is appreciated guys, thnQ very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you may not have added the Google Play Services SDK to your project.
See the documentation at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: hey @GreyBeardedGeek i have addd Google Play Services SDK to my project though having same error, can you suggest some solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

LocationClient is a deprecated class. However, it is still in the Android documentation to get the current location.

[Android LocationClient class is deprecated but used in documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation)