# Android LocationClient class is deprecated but used in documentation

Tags: android

If we go through the documentation of the [`LocationClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html), we can see that the class is deprecated.

But the deprecated class is used in the [documentation to get the current location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

I think this is little bit misleading or am i looking at incorrect documentations?

Comment: As always, they deprecate apis but they don't update the docs at the same time. You'll have to wait until the docs are updated or try to find a working example

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Again Google has released a new API but they haven't updated the documentation :$ After spend some time trying to figure out how it works I got it, here you have a full example using the new/latest Location Service API... Enjoy developing :)

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private final String TAG = "MyAwesomeApp";

    private TextView mLocationView;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLocationView = new TextView(this);

        setContentView(mLocationView);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationView.setText("Location received: " + location.toString());
    }
}
```

and do not forget to add this permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Note: if you just need to get the last location (without updates), you can use `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)` from OnConnected

Comment: Thanks for the example. In the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) on the Google Dev Site, there was an _To check that the APK is installed, call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` ..._ part. Is that necessary here, also? Where should I put that part?

Comment: Nagy, you check for google play service right before the mGoogleApiClient.connect() call, and only connect if the value = ConnectionResult.SUCCESS

Comment: Is there a similar code example on how to use the LocationServices.GeofencingAPI?

Comment: Good answer. Just merge it with some old components/stuff and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Some questions: Is there a call back if the Location Request failed? Or is the same callbacks for the Google API client used for this is well?

Comment: Note that if you just want to get the last location without updates, you can use `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);` from OnConnected

Comment: How would you go about stopping an on-going location request?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, it was just what I was looking for thnaks!

Comment: Thanks. It's crazy Google still haven't updated their API docs. Bug filed here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82907 probably a duplicate - but hey. They deserve it :)

Comment: @InquisitorJax I second that. Does anyone know how to add Geofencing to this? Can't find it anywhere and the docs are outdated.

Comment: You don't need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>` . `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` includes both.

Comment: Once again, really lousy handling of library updates by Google!

Comment: Notice, that without `mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);` (or any other interval) you won't get any location updates. Took me some time to find that out...

Comment: did not work despite i change the location by lots of meters

Comment: Hey this is working well +1 for this. But how can I use this code to get user location even in background? Or how can I use this code as `service` ??

Comment: @NoOne yes of course, you can use that code from a Service and it will work like a charm

Comment: But I cant figure out how to do this. Can you please answer this question for me? It has same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327713/how-to-use-google-location-service-api-to-get-location-updates-even-in-backgroun    Please add sample code. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Okay thank you very much. This is working perfect in `service` class also :)

Comment: FusedLocationApi is deprecated

Comment: could be good to have the conversion of the given sample to the new FusedLocationProviderClient as now FusedLocationApi is deprecated

Comment: 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient' is deprecated 
 Inspection info: Reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

Comment: GoogleApiClient is deprecated

Answer (score 22):

Some of the documentation is old in Google (some examples you mentioned still use the deprecated `LocationClient`). 
You have to use the new GoogleApiClient as described in the location Services examples:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
     .addApi(LocationServices.API)
     .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
     .build()
```

and when the new client is connected, you can use the fused location api for example like this:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(theNewClient, 
    locationRequest, locationListener);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get latitude and longitude.?

Comment: FusedLocationApi is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was covered in the [developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html). For LocationClient, you'd use this in conjunction with [LocationServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html) which then leads us to [GeofencingApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html).

Comment: Six months later after the release of that new Google Play API and the documentation has not yet been updated.

Comment: It also looks like the official LocationProvider app from Google is still using the LocationClient which no longer exist inside this package import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;

Answer (score 4):

LocationClient is removed. GoogleApiClient is api to use for Google Play services Location APIs.

The sample code for the common scenarios is [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) and the training classes [were updated](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) with more coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) update code..

```
package iwannado.com.myapplicationforsha1key;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapWithMapViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG = MapWithMapViewActivity.class.getCanonicalName();


    private GoogleMap mMap = null;
    private MapView mMapView = null;

    private EditText loatcationEditText = null;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    private Location mLocationRequest = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_with_map_view);
        loatcationEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loatcation_edit_text);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        /*
        * The method is used to create mapView
        * */
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*
        *The method Return Google map
        * */
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        gotoCurrentLoactionGooglePlayService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;



    }



    private void gotoCurrentLoactionGooglePlayService() {
        /*working with new google api for laction..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25173057
* */
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
/*
* Follow this documentation.. https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
*
* Please add Runtime permission here for android 6
* */
        mLocationRequest = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLocationRequest != null) {

           LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLocationRequest.getLatitude(),mLocationRequest.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Programmatically Current Loaction"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            Toast.makeText(this,"getLatitude() = "+String.valueOf(mLocationRequest.getLatitude())+"\n getLongitude() = "+String.valueOf(mLocationRequest.getLongitude()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Toast.makeText(this,"Location received: " + location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You just simply add this in your code,**

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

 oncreate(){
  .
  .
  FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            mLastLocation =location;
            if (mLastLocation!= null) {
                LogUtils.logE(TAG, "Lat: " + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "Long: " + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            }

        }
    });
  .
  .
  }
```

According to the **documentation** update code..