# Android LocationServices.GeofencingApi example usage

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

Does anyone know of an example of using the LocationServices.GeofencingApi?
All the android geofencing examples I find are using the deprecated LocationClient class.
From what I can see, the LocationServices class is the one to use, but there doesn't seem to be any working examples on how to use it.

The closest I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation) post highlighting location update requests

UPDATE: The closest answer I've found is [this git example](https://github.com/jdellinger/AnDevConNov2014-LocationServicesDemoProject/tree/newapi) project - but it still uses the deprecated LocationClient to get triggered fences.

Comment: did you tried at the source: http://d.android.com at training section acronym of article title is CaMG

Comment: The specific link is here http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
which uses the deprecated LocationClient class - seems they haven't updated the documentation yet

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just migrated my code to the new API. Here is a working example:

A working project on GitHub based on this answer: https://github.com/androidfu/GeofenceExample

> This helper class registers the geofences using the API. I use a callback interface to communicate with the calling activity/fragment. You can build a callback that fits your needs.

```
public class GeofencingRegisterer implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private List<Geofence> geofencesToAdd;
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

    private GeofencingRegistererCallbacks mCallback;

    public final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    public GeofencingRegisterer(Context context){
        mContext =context;
    }

    public void setGeofencingCallback(GeofencingRegistererCallbacks callback){
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public void registerGeofences(List<Geofence> geofences){
        geofencesToAdd = geofences;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if(mCallback != null){
            mCallback.onApiClientConnected();
        }

        mGeofencePendingIntent = createRequestPendingIntent();
        PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, geofencesToAdd, mGeofencePendingIntent);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    // Successfully registered
                    if(mCallback != null){
                        mCallback.onGeofencesRegisteredSuccessful();
                    }
                } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                    // Google provides a way to fix the issue
                    /*
                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                            mContext,     // your current activity used to receive the result
                            RESULT_CODE); // the result code you'll look for in your
                    // onActivityResult method to retry registering
                    */
                } else {
                    // No recovery. Weep softly or inform the user.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registering failed: " + status.getStatusMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if(mCallback != null){
            mCallback.onApiClientSuspended();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if(mCallback != null){
            mCallback.onApiClientConnectionFailed(connectionResult);
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }



    /**
     * Returns the current PendingIntent to the caller.
     *
     * @return The PendingIntent used to create the current set of geofences
     */
    public PendingIntent getRequestPendingIntent() {
        return createRequestPendingIntent();
    }

    /**
     * Get a PendingIntent to send with the request to add Geofences. Location
     * Services issues the Intent inside this PendingIntent whenever a geofence
     * transition occurs for the current list of geofences.
     *
     * @return A PendingIntent for the IntentService that handles geofence
     * transitions.
     */
    private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeofencingReceiver.class);
            return PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
    }
}
```

> This class is the base class for your geofence transition receiver.

```
public abstract class ReceiveGeofenceTransitionIntentService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Sets an identifier for this class' background thread
     */
    public ReceiveGeofenceTransitionIntentService() {
        super("ReceiveGeofenceTransitionIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if(event != null){

            if(event.hasError()){
                onError(event.getErrorCode());
            } else {
                int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
                if(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL || transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
                    String[] geofenceIds = new String[event.getTriggeringGeofences().size()];
                    for (int index = 0; index < event.getTriggeringGeofences().size(); index++) {
                        geofenceIds[index] = event.getTriggeringGeofences().get(index).getRequestId();
                    }

                    if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
                        onEnteredGeofences(geofenceIds);
                    } else if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                        onExitedGeofences(geofenceIds);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    protected abstract void onEnteredGeofences(String[] geofenceIds);

    protected abstract void onExitedGeofences(String[] geofenceIds);

    protected abstract void onError(int errorCode);
}
```

> This class implements the abstract class and does all the handling of geofence transitions

```
public class GeofencingReceiver extends ReceiveGeofenceTransitionIntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onEnteredGeofences(String[] geofenceIds) {
        Log.d(GeofencingReceiver.class.getName(), "onEnter");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onExitedGeofences(String[] geofenceIds) {
        Log.d(GeofencingReceiver.class.getName(), "onExit");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(int errorCode) {
        Log.e(GeofencingReceiver.class.getName(), "Error: " + i);
    }
}
```

> And in your manifest add:

```
<service
        android:name="**xxxxxxx**.GeofencingReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</service>
```

> Callback Interface

```
public interface GeofencingRegistererCallbacks {
    public void onApiClientConnected();
    public void onApiClientSuspended();
    public void onApiClientConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult);

    public void onGeofencesRegisteredSuccessful();
}
```

Comment: could you provide your callback too? I am new to android development, would be nice if you could share your code :) thx

Comment: According to the docs, the method ```LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(GoogleApiClient, List<Geofence>, PendingIntent);``` is deprecated, too. Use ```LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(GoogleApiClient, GeofencingRequest, PendingIntent);``` instead, by creating a ```GeofencingRequest``` first: ```GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder().addGeofences(mGeofencesToAdd).build();```

Comment: Nice, they changed the docs again.. last week it was not deprecated

Comment: Why is GeofencingReceiver service exported?

Comment: I can't explain this, I found this in an other documentation of the geofencing API. Maybe it is because the service is called by google play services framework.

Comment: But IntentService cannot run after it is finished!  What if I want a service to run indefinitely in the background?

Comment: Why would you want this? The IntentService is called everytime Google Play Services acknowledges a geofence transition