# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: PendingIntent's target package can't be different from the request package

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Hi am getting this error after Location Permission request success. after permission success am requesting location using LocationService as follows.

```
 LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mApiClient, mGeofenceList, mGeofenceRequestIntent);
```

I searched on google regarding this, i can not find out exact solution to solve this issue as this is instant app module. But in my project apk module location request working file without any issue.

here is my complete log

```
  E/Isotope: UID: [10135]  PID: [21567] IActivityManagerProxy : Instant app: xxx.yyy.zzz crashed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=42, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {xxx.yyy.zzz/com.karumi.dexter.DexterActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: PendingIntent's target package can't be different to the request package.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: PendingIntent's target package can't be different to the request package.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf$1.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf$1.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.yyy.zzz.activity.HomeActivity$1.onPermissionGranted(HomeActivity.java:219)
    at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsListenerToPermissionListenerAdapter.onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsListenerToPermissionListenerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator$1.run(MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator.java:45)
    at com.karumi.dexter.MainThread.execute(MainThread.java:32)
    at com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator.onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionListenerThreadDecorator.java:43)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.onPermissionsChecked(DexterInstance.java:278)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.updatePermissionsAsGranted(DexterInstance.java:252)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterInstance.onPermissionRequestGranted(DexterInstance.java:141)
    at com.karumi.dexter.Dexter.onPermissionsRequested(Dexter.java:175)
    at com.karumi.dexter.DexterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(DexterActivity.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7098)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6950)
```

Code for pending intent

```
  private PendingIntent getGeofenceTransitionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(xxx.yyy.zzz.activity.HomeActivity.this, xxx.yyy.zzz.activity.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: `LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(GoogleApiClient, List<Geofence>, PendingIntent);` is deprecated. Use `LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(GoogleApiClient, GeofencingRequest, PendingIntent);` instead, by creating a GeofencingRequest first: `GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder().addGeofences(mGeofencesToAdd).build();`

Comment: I will check and let you know #Shailesh

Comment: I checked with your code. Not working. It seems the error is because of PendingIntent not the GeofencingRequest.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633796/android-locationservices-geofencingapi-example-usage

Comment: Post your pendingIntent. The error says it involves the package name used, so what package did you use vs your app's package name?

Comment: added pending intent code

Comment: what happens when you change the `this` in `getService(this,...` so it specifically references the same package?

Comment: Oh, and when you run this as an installed-app, does this exception happen?

Comment: No. apk works fine. instant app only gives error

Comment: Please file this issue to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 You will need to provide a sample project.