# import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting this compile error.I had added the google play services lib in same workspace.Then added the latest sdk(tools,extras) successfully.

But I didn't know why this error still occurs.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;  -->import cannot be resolved


public class Main extends Activity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationClient mLocationClient;   --->LocationClient cannot be resolved to a type


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}
}
```

In **Console:**

I am getting this, No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

**Manifest:**

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

........
</application>
```

**Edit:**

[image]

[image]

Anybody can help me with this.Thanking you.

Comment: Check library reference. I think Google play library reference not proper!

Comment: @BhavinChauhan its perfectly right.I am sure about it.I put it in same workspace

Comment: reference is fine as per edit question :) try to restart eclipse

Comment: @BhavinChauhan I tried clean and restart eclipse.but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) seem to be updated now.

I had the same problem about a week ago the problem is because the `GooglePlayServices` library is updated and also the `LocationClient` was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation) as well *([but the docs were not updated](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html))*. You must have updated the `GooglePlayServices` library and then this error occurred.

So instead of using the old `LocationClient` you need to use **`com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient`** and **`com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest`**.

See the docs for [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html) and [LocationRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html)

Comment: I am added that two imports.but still error occurred.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation to resolve this and make sure you have updated the **Google Play Services library** and **Google Repository**. and also dont forget to import the updated library in your project.

Comment: Note: all the docs are indeed updated at this time :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `LocationClient` is deprecated for new `Google Play Services`. And i think you have already used a latest google play service. So you just change your `LocationClient` with `GoogleApiClient` which is replaced with `LocationClient`  for new latest `Google play services` which will solve your issue.

Further more you can visit this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html)