# Using Geofence with google api v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-geofence

I am trying to create the Geofence in google location api-V2 But class LocationClient is not found in the latest version of google location library.

Is there any way to use Geofence with google api-V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use the GeoFence api? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html, https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html
Otherwise here's a thread on the deprecation of LocationClient: [Android LocationClient class is deprecated but used in documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation)

Comment: How to get the unique id generated after the creation of a geofence? Since, it this id is needed to attach the entities to be tracked with geofence.

Comment: I think you need to use `Geofence.Builder setRequestId (String requestId)` and then `Geofence getRequestId()`

Comment: yes! I am already doing that. I am confused that when I would add the entities with this geofence, then, Should I consider this REQUEST_ID as the unique id with which I will add the entities to?

Answer (score 0):

Aaahhhh..... GoogleApiClient class is doing the work here:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(apiClient, geoRequest, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: For detailed info see: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi.html