# Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, android-activity, instantiation

I am trying to use GooglePlaceAPI for getting current places
 when i use Google Play Services as dependencies it causes the error that my main activity cannot be found.
Following is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();


        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i("TAG", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My log is here:

```
09-12 21:53:51.796: W/ResourceType(9470): Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
09-12 21:53:51.802: I/art(9470): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.myproject.MainActivity>
09-12 21:53:51.804: D/AndroidRuntime(9470): Shutting down VM
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): Process: com.example.myproject, PID: 9470
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myproject/com.example.myproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myproject.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myproject-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myproject.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myproject-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     ... 10 more
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myproject.MainActivity
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         ... 14 more
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myproject.MainActivity
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):         ... 13 more
09-12 21:53:51.823: E/AndroidRuntime(9470):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
09-12 21:53:51.848: I/Process(9470): Sending signal. PID: 9470 SIG: 9
```

My Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="MY_KEY"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have a look at this question here, maybe it can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path

Comment: @Noahnder i saw that post it does not solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="MY_KEY"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

As it is sufficient to declare your package name in the beginning of the Manifest.

Comment: did you take a look at this answer? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation). Seems like he has the same problem.