# How to get GoogleApiClient in Xamarin?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, google-api

I want to implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173057/2611340) in my Android application that I'm developing in Xamarin but can not find a namespace in which the `GoogleApiClient` is. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GoogleApiClient` is in the `Android.Gms.Common.Apis` namespace.

That namespace is in the "*Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement*" assembly, but you do not install that directly.

So, assuming you are trying to access that in doing some Android Location/Map development, install this nuget:

[Xamarin Google Play Services - Location](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location/27.0.0)

> Xamarin.Android Bindings for Google Play Services - Location
>
> One of the unique features of mobile applications is location
>   awareness. Mobile users take their devices with them everywhere, and
>   adding location awareness to your app offers users a more contextual
>   experience. The location APIs available in Google Play services
>   facilitate adding location awareness to your app with automated
>   location tracking, geofencing, and activity recognition.
>
> To install Xamarin Google Play Services - Location, run the following
>   command in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location
```

**Using clause:**

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
```

**Code:**

```
var foo = GoogleApiClient ();
```

Comment: I was failed to resolve GoogleApiAvailability class but after installing location its resolved.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to RobertN answer, it seems there were some [naming/namespace changes in **27.0.0.0**](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54499/google-play-services-v27-migration#latest).

So here's an example that might help:

```
GoogleApiClient api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (Application.Context, this, this)
    .AddApi (Android.Gms.Location.LocationServices.API)
    .Build ();
```

In the above code *this* means that the below interfaces are implemented:

- Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks
- Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the command "Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" also works for updating the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices. It will always fail if you try to use the UI to update the components.