# How to get GoogleApiClient instance in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to integrate my xamarin android app with google play services leaderboards and achievements. I am not getting how to convert below code from [android documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#obtaining_the_google_api_client_and_connecting) to c#.

```
   // Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Game and Drive services.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // Drive API
            .build();

    // ...
```

I tried to convert something like below

```
GoogleApiClient api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .AddApi(Android.Gms.Games.API)
           .Build();
```

It's giving error under "Android.Gms.Games.API"

None of the things mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391731/how-to-get-googleapiclient-in-xamarin) stack overflow thread are working. Looks like most of these things deprecated.

Please suggest if any other easy way available to integrate with leaderboards.

**EDIT:** Made changes and now giving below error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to get access to `GoogleClientAPI` via:

```
var googleClientAPI = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Application.Context).AddApi(XXX).Build();
```

#### Example using a blocking connect as a quick test:

```
var client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Application.Context)
                                .AddApi(GamesClass.API)
                                .AddScope(GamesClass.ScopeGames)
                                .Build();
Task.Run(() => {
    client.BlockingConnect();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(client.IsConnected);
});
```

#### Note: This **assumes** that you have registered your app, otherwise you will get a fatal developer error... see [Play Connecting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#obtaining_the_google_api_client_and_connecting)

---

Since you are needing access to leaderboard and achievements, make sure that you have added the packages:

- `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games`
- `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Identity`

These will auto-include the `.Base` and `.Basement` package

---

- Namespaces to look at after adding the packages:

---

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Games.LeaderBoard;
using Android.Gms.Games.Achievement;
```

Comment: Cool. Looks like I added all references already. I didn't follow the syntax as you mentioned. I am good now. Thank you...

Comment: I made changes as you said. Now it's giving error. See my edit in the question.

Comment: @RajKarri I added an example, make sure that you have registered your app (see note)