# how to Fused location Run in Background service continuously

Tags: android, google-maps, service, fuse

Hi I want to write Fused location in Service which run in background continuously. where i can write code for send location to server. I have implement it in Activity now i want to implement it in Service.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can extends the Service and implemetns the methods

`public class BackgroundLocationService extends Service implements
  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener`

Check this code for implementation [Background location services.](https://gist.github.com/blackcj/20efe2ac885c7297a676)

remember just remove your location updates properly. otherwise service will not stop by calling stopService method

Comment: private LocationClient mLocationClient; method is now deprecated

Comment: have you checked the link?

Comment: yes. i have check this link this link used LocationClient now its deprecated

Comment: check this and change method according to new method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation